# Q: How to remove the limit of 1000 records per request

Tags: socrata, soda

I am running this endpoint https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/qx3q-zr7u.json?limit=1000

I put a limit of a thousand records but I receive the following message

Unrecognized arguments [limit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `$` symbol before the query keyword. This query will work:

```
https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/qx3q-zr7u.json?$limit=1000
```